# Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse erro: A RenderFlex overflowed by 473 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:singlecheff/consts/consts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:singlecheff/functions/fn_business.dart';
import 'package:singlecheff/functions/fn_utils.dart';

class CategoriasViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  CategoriasViewPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _CategoriasViewPage createState() => new _CategoriasViewPage();
}

class _CategoriasViewPage extends State<CategoriasViewPage> {
  String url;

  @override
  void initState() {
    url = prefs.getString('serverHost') + 'listar_grupos';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Categorias"),
        backgroundColor: secondColor,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            confirmarVoltarParaControles(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchData(url).then((response) {
            return jsonDecode(response.body)['Data'];
          }),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              List<dynamic> result = snapshot.data;
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            controleAtual['descr_controle'],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: result.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                                margin: defaultMargin20,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.apps),
                                  title: Text(result[index]['gru_descricao']),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    grupoAtual = result[index]['gru_id'];
                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                        .pushNamed("/subcategorias");
                                  },
                                ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return SpinKitDualRing(
                color: secondColor,
                size: 50.0,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Está dando esse erro:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 473 pixels on the bottom.

Já tentei usar o `SingleChildScrollView`, mas ele funcionou só na parte de cima, agora no `ListView.builder` ele não funcionou.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Comment: eu não consigo simular pq não tenho os dados, mas tente colocar   ListView.builder() dentro de um  Expanded()

Answer (score -1):

Não consegui rodar seu código original por ter arquivos faltando, mas corrigi pra um bem semelhante e espero te direcionar. Como você tem uma listview dentro de outra, é preciso utilizar a propriedade physics para informar o comportamento que ela vai ter. Eu atribuído o comportamento de juntar as duas listviews como se fossem uma com o parâmetro seguinte:

```
//physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()


    
final loremIpsum = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
        "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an "
        "unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It"
        " has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, "
        "remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of "
        "Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing "
        "software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    .split(" ");

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Categorias"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "controleAtual",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: loremIpsum.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.apps),
                      title: Text(loremIpsum[index]),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/subcategorias");
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).